# Tableau Incremental Refresh Using SQL Query

Tags: sql, tableau-desktop

I have a question regarding incremental refresh with SQL Query on a Tableau Server.

My plan was the following:

1. Run the query for data till yesterday(i.e 20/7/2021) . After this I will have the full extract until that Date.
2. The next day(22/7/2021), I will build a flow that will do this. Each day will run the query for the previous day (21/7/2021)  and UNION the data with the extract. In that way, I will have the incremental extract using the SQL Query.

Problem:

For that Procedure, I must use the Output Extract, that the flow will produce.
I tried this Procedure on my local machine, but, Tableau Prep gives me the following Error.

[image: Error]

What's the best solution to approach this problem? Is there a better way?
I also attach the full Flow.

[image: Flow]

Thank you in advance.